# "setTitle" method not work

Tags: iphone, uibutton

every one.
I'm developing iphone app.

I try to change the Button's title in my code.
When i click a button, then the title will change the other text.

So, i use setTitle method, but the app is killed.

The code is following.

```
-(IBAction)deleteProject:(id)sender{

    UIButton *button = (UIButton *) sender;
    if (addButton.enabled == YES ){

        addButton.enabled = NO ;

        //Here, the code is stopped.
        [button setTitle:@"Back" forstate:UIControlStateNormal];
        //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

        [mainTableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    }

    else{

        addButton.enabled = YES;

        //Here, the code is stopped. V
        [button setTitle:@"Delete" forstate:UIControlStateNormal];
        //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

        [mainTableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: what error are you getting, exactly, as reported on the console?

Comment: Your if condition should compare two values but now it is assigning, so it will always go inside if condition.Change your if condition to if (addButton.enabled == YES ).

Comment: It is the console window. ----------------------------------[UIBarButtonItem setTitle:forState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x681dcf0

Comment: @NuzhatZari is right. You should also be getting a compiler (or analyser) warning - you shouldn't ignore those!

Comment: A `UIBarButtonItem` is not the same as a `UIButton`. If it is, in fact a bar button item, you should replace the button with a new one instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get passed a `sender` parameter into your `deleteProject:` method. This parameter is type `id`, which can be anything.

You cast it to `UIButton` and try to use it as a `UIButton`.

The exception you get is `[UIBarButtonItem setTitle:forState:]`

This should tell you that `sender` isn't a `UIButton` at all, it's a `UIBarButtonItem` :)

You can test this but putting this code at the start of your `deleteProject:` method.

```
if (NO == [sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
    NSLog(@"Oh no, sender isn't a button, it's a %@", [sender class]);
}
```

Comment: Then, how can i set the title of UIButtonItem class?

Comment: `UIBarButtonItem` inherits from `UIBarItem` which has a `title` property. I guess something like `((UIBarButtonItem*)sender).title = @"My Title";` would do it :)

Comment: (Docs for UIBarButtonItem : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html and for UIBarItem : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: However, the docs say you should set the title before adding it to the bar. You might have to either remove the item, change it's title and re-add it or have two items and swap them over :)

Answer (score 0):

Capital **S** in `setTitle:forState:`

Also, use `==` for comparison, `=` for assignment. An assignment is always `true`.

Comment: _An assignment is always true_ isn't true :) What about `if (x = NO) { A } else { B }` will do `B` ;)

Comment: @deanWombourne You're right; an assignment will evaluate to the assigned value. `if (x=NO)` evaluates as `if (NO)` (which is false), and `if (x=5)` evaluates as `if (5)` (which is true). What I should have said, is that *this* assignment will always be true.

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled the setTitle:forState method in the UIButton class. Corrected spelling below for your convenience.

```
 -(IBAction)deleteProject:(id)sender{

    UIButton *button = (UIButton *) sender;
    if (addButton.enabled == YES ) // you could also use if (addButton.enabled)
    {

        addButton.enabled = NO ;

        [button setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [mainTableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    }

    else // addButton.enabled == NO
    {

        addButton.enabled = YES;

        [button setTitle:@"Delete" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [mainTableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
    }
 }
```